# How to `Erase the scroll-back (aka "Saved Lines")` in the terminal

Tags: go, terminal

How can I erase the scroll-back in a terminal using Go?

In OS X using Terminal, I can run:

```
$ print '\e[3J'
```

and it will "Erase the scroll-back (aka 'Saved Lines')." Great!

But, in Go, when I run:

```
exec.Command("print", `\e[3J`).CombinedOutput()
```

I get the error that `exec: "print": executable file not found in $PATH`, which makes sense:

```
$ type -a print
print is a shell builtin
```

The helpful Gophers in Slack mentioned I should look into communicating the the terminal app directly (whether it be Terminal, iTerm, iTerm2, etc.). However, I'm at a loss even after looking at this: https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html

Comment: Eh? Bash has no `print` builtin. Maybe you're using `zsh`, and this question is incorrectly tagged?

Comment: (Regardless, if you were going to use an external command for this, that command should be `tput`, which can look up the right sequence to use for your current `TERM` value; otherwise, your code will be necessarily terminal-specific).

Comment: Good call, I'll remove the tags for better accuracy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fmt.Printf(string([]byte{0x1b,'[', '3', 'J'}))
```

should suffice. But you really should use a terminal library, which knows which codes to use depending on the terminal emulator in use.

Something like [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go).

For the usually available codes and their byte values, you can
try [xterm-docu](https://www.xfree86.org/4.8.0/ctlseqs.html) but your
mileage may vary, as you use different terminal emulators.

Answer (score 2):

`print` is a shell builtin, so it cannot be executed from go. You could use the `/bin/echo` binary, `/usr/bin/clear`, or just `fmt.Println` the escape sequence:

```
seq := "\x1b\x5b\x48"

// option 1
out, _ := exec.Command("/bin/echo", seq).Output()
fmt.Println(string(out))

// option 2
out, _ := exec.Command("/usr/bin/clear").Output()
fmt.Println(string(out))

// option 3 (prefered)
fmt.Println(seq)
```

Comment: `/bin/echo`'s behavior is undefined with any sequence containing a backslash -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html. Much better to use `printf` (as suggested in the APPLICATION USAGE section of the docs for `echo`)... though of course, using any external command here at all rather than doing the output direct from Go (as in your Option 3) is silly in the extreme.